# Controller is not registered error after adding ngRoute `.config`

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-module

### Controller is not recognizing - AngularJS error

I've a controller defined in `controllerPloyee.js` called `controllerPloyee` which was working before i added the `ngRoute` and made to route. The error that shows is

> angular.min.js:127 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.8/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=controllerPloyee

I've checked the documentation and another questions with the same error, but doesn't help.

Index.html

```
<html ng-app="ployee">
<head>
    <!--Angular-->
    <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-route.js"></script>
    <!--JS-->
    <script src="assets/js/moduloPloyee.js"></script>
    <!--Controllers-->
    <script src="assets/js/controllers/controllerPloyee.js"></script>
    <!--Services-->
    <script src="services/routeConfig.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <div ng-include="'view/footer.html'"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

routeConfig.js

```
angular.module('ployee', ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        templateUrl: "view/login.html",
        controller: "controllerPloyee"
    }).when('/',{
        templateUrl: "view/login.html",
        controller: "controllerPloyee"
    }).otherwise({redirectTo: "/login"})
})
```

controllerPloyee.js

```
angular.module('ployee').controller('controllerPloyee',  function($scope){
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script that creates the module needs to be placed before the others:

```
<!--Angular-->
<script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-route.js"></script>
<!-- IMPORTANT needs to be place here -->
<script src="services/routeConfig.js"></script>
<!--JS-->
<script src="assets/js/moduloPloyee.js"></script>
<!--Controllers-->
<script src="assets/js/controllers/controllerPloyee.js"></script>
<!--Services-->
̶<̶s̶c̶r̶i̶p̶t̶ ̶s̶r̶c̶=̶"̶s̶e̶r̶v̶i̶c̶e̶s̶/̶r̶o̶u̶t̶e̶C̶o̶n̶f̶i̶g̶.̶j̶s̶"̶>̶<̶/̶s̶c̶r̶i̶p̶t̶>̶
```

The statement `angular.module('ployee', ['ngRoute'])` creates a new module. The statement `angular.module('ployee')` retrieves the module for further configuration.

When the module is created *after* the controller script, the controller is lost. This is why the script that creates the module needs to be placed before other scripts which add controllers, services, filters, directives, constants, etc.

A module is a container for your app.

Passing one argument retrieves an existing `angular.Module`, whereas passing more than one argument creates a new [angular.Module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module).

From the Docs:<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval)</sup>

> ### Creation versus Retrieval
>
> Beware that using `angular.module('myModule', [])` will create the module `myModule` and **overwrite any existing module named `myModule`.** Use `angular.module('myModule')` to retrieve an existing module.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `angular.module` Function API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module)
- [AngularJS `angular.Module` Type API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - modules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)