# A controller with this name is not registered -- Error: $controller:ctrlreg

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

### Property Binding | AngularJS

We were trying to use property binding in **AngularJS** Directives,but the problem raised the error stated as

> The controller with the name `counterController` is not registered.

We would like to pass the `variable:firstcount` from `counterController` to `orderController`. The `variable:firstcount` needs to be increment/decrement on click of a button.

Can someone help us resolve the error?

### app.js

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('mainApp', []);

}());
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mainApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller='counterController as counter'>
        <counter count="counter.firstcount"></counter>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="counterController.js"></script>
    <script src="orderController.js"></script>
    <script src="counter.directive.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

### orderController.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('mainApp', [])
        .controller('orderController', orderController);

    orderController.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function orderController($scope) {
        this.count=$scope.count;
        console.log("Inside OrderController");

        this.increment = function () {
            this.count++;
        }

        this.decrement = function () {
            this.count--;
        }

    };

}());
```

### counterController.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('mainApp', [])
        .controller('counterController', counterController);

    counterController.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function counterController($scope) {
        var counter = this;
        counter.firstcount = 10;
        console.log("Inside Counter Controller");

        counter.increment=function(){
            counter.count++;
        }

        counter.decrement=function(){
            counter.count--;
        }
    };

}());
```

### counter.directive.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function counter() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                count: '='
            },
            controller: 'orderController as order',
            template: `
                 Counter: <input type="text" ng-model="order.count">
                 <button type="button" ng-click="order.increment()">Increment</button> 
                 <button type="button" ng-click="order.decrement()">Decrement</button>
            `
        };
    }

    angular.module('mainApp')
        .directive('counter', counter);

}());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the dependency argument in the controller definitions:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    ̶a̶n̶g̶u̶l̶a̶r̶.̶m̶o̶d̶u̶l̶e̶(̶'̶m̶a̶i̶n̶A̶p̶p̶'̶,̶ ̶[̶]̶)̶
    angular.module('mainApp')
        .controller('orderController', orderController);
```

> > Beware that using `angular.module('myModule', [])` will create the module `myModule` and **overwrite any existing module named `myModule`.** Use `angular.module('myModule')` to retrieve an existing module.
>
> — [AngularJS Developer Guide - modules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Error Reference - Error: $controller:ctrlreg](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$controller/ctrlreg)
- [Controller is not registered error after adding ngRoute `.config`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58807817/controller-is-not-registered-error-after-adding-ngroute-config/58808002#58808002)

Answer (score 3):

You continue to define the app module so instead of doing this everytime:

```
angular.module('mainApp', [])
```

Do this instead:

```
angular.module('mainApp')
```

You actually do follow that pattern in your counter.directive.js. You should only have:

```
angular.module('mainApp', [])
```

Once in your app, in the app.js file likely.